# PHP sock linked to update-alternatives choice?

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

In my nginx configs, I point to PHP as `/var/run/php8.3-fpm.sock`.

Because there is a specific version in that path, using `update-alternatives` does not change the PHP version my websites use.

How do I have a socket that points to whatever PHP version I chose using `update-alternatives`?

There's currently no version-agnostic sock file in `/var/run` that I could point to.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by ᴍᴇʜᴏᴠ, Debian *does* support `update-alternatives` for the socket, but it does it a little differently, and there are two requirements:

- You must be running a PHP-FPM package from **Feb 1 2020** or later (which hopefully you are)
- You must be running **systemd** versus sysvinit

The generic socket, located at `/run/php/php-fpm.sock`, is created by the systemd unit file by calling `/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper` via the `ExecStartPost` and `ExecStopPost` directives. If you wish to use this socket, you still need to ensure your web server config is pointed to it versus the version-specific file.

The original answer is below if you don't meet those requirements.

---

It appears you are running a Debian/Ubuntu based distribution, which intentionally installs php-fpm in version specific locations (it's the whole reason you can use `update-alternatives` to switch the default version on the fly). However, there is no alternatives config for the socket files of php-fpm (your call to `update-alternatives` is only changing the CLI PHP version at `/usr/bin/php`).

The socket file to use is defined in `/etc/php/8.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`.

```
; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv4 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   '[ip:6:addr:ess]:port' - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv6 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses
;                            (IPv6 and IPv4-mapped) on a specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = /run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock
```

If you **really** want to have a version agnostic socket file, you can change that setting to just be `listen = /run/php/php-fpm.sock` and update your nginx config accordingly. You'll need to do this for every version of PHP you have installed, and it also means you cannot have two different php-fpm versions running simultaneously.

You might be able to play around with creating your own `update-alternative` config for `/run/php/php-fpm.sock` that allows you to switch between versions, but I'm not sure how well that will work trying to manage files in `/run` that way.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be a problem on Debian 11, and I can use both `/run/php/php-fpm.sock` as well as `/etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock`.

```
# ls -la /run/php
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 260 Mar 29 19:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root     root     600 Mar 29 19:24 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root       3 Mar 29 19:24 php5.6-fpm.pid
srw-rw----  1 www-data www-data   0 Mar 29 19:24 php5.6-fpm.sock
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root       3 Mar 29 19:24 php7.3-fpm.pid
srw-rw----  1 www-data www-data   0 Mar 29 19:24 php7.3-fpm.sock
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root       3 Mar 29 19:24 php7.4-fpm.pid
srw-rw----  1 www-data www-data   0 Mar 29 19:24 php7.4-fpm.sock
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root       3 Mar 29 19:24 php8.2-fpm.pid
srw-rw----  1 www-data www-data   0 Mar 29 19:24 php8.2-fpm.sock
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root       3 Mar 29 19:24 php8.3-fpm.pid
srw-rw----  1 www-data www-data   0 Mar 29 19:24 php8.3-fpm.sock
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root     root      30 Mar 29 19:24 php-fpm.sock -> /etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock
```

See where `/etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock` points to:

```
# stat /etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock
  File: /etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock -> /run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock
```

Let's reconfigure PHP to 5.6 using the below command. It will present you with available versions and prompt for a number.

```
update-alternatives --config php-fpm.sock
```

Check again:

```
# stat /etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock
  File: /etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock -> /run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock
```